# css Zoom not adapting the Width of my DIV in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Got a weird problem, I must be doing something really stupid cuz this should be easy. I am trying to use zoom inside my div. Now it works when I use chrome, but when I display it in IE it seems to have adapted the height but not the width, even though both of them are fixed. Here's a simplified version of what I am talking about:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    td, .Outer, .Inner {
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    table {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .Outer {
        zoom: 0.5; 
        background-color: yellow; 
        text-align: center;
    }

    .Inner {
        height: 1218px;
        width: 1010px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    td {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="Outer" style="">OUTER TEXT
                <div class="Inner" style="">INNERTEXT</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to make IE act the same as Chrome?

IE (it's only the green box that is bigger btw):

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

Cheers

Comment: If that is your complete HTML, you're displaying things in quirks mode, which may confuse the matter. Different browsers have different quirks! Anyway, I can't really see any difference between IE and Chrome: both show a large 626×742 rectangle. Mozilla on the other hand...

Comment: weird, it's not similar with me, it's showing me double the width in IE. it should be the 626x742 one but for some reason my IE is showing double the width. This is IE 11

Comment: Yeah, same here, IE11 under Win 8.1. You don't have the page zoomed in manually by mistake?

Comment: Here I added 2 pics to show the difference. Ur right about firefox, didn't think of that. This is an extra problem :/ Basically I needed a zoomed div which contains an entire html pages code (it's the html i will print after this screen), working as a mini preview

Comment: Stupid question, but does this happen only when you have `zoom`? It looks like IE believes tables should be 100% wide. So can you confirm that tables work normally under normal circumstances? There are no other factors, such as a user stylesheet?

Comment: there's no user stylesheets no, this is literally the only code im using in this example. If i modify the width of the .Inner class the green box adapts, it's like the red one isn't even coloring it's entire width, super weird

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions at the moment, I'm sorry.